# Which metadata definition format to use with doctrine 2 and symfony 2

Tags: symfony, orm, annotations, doctrine-orm, yaml

I'm starting to use Symfony 2 after some time using Symfony 1.4. I would like to know which metadata format is the easiest and fastest to learn and use.

I know people like to clean their hands when it comes to say something is better than some other thing, specially when those things are supposed to be equivalent. Nevertheless, I'm  asking you to make a recommendation considering the folowing:

1. I have some experience with Symfony 1.4, using YAML format
2. The amount of documentation about each format.
3. Any other thing you may consider that I'm not xD

Comment: I myself am an annotation fan since everything ends up in one file making it easy to see how the properties are defined and validated..  On the other hand, everything does end up in one file which can clutter up your file and make it hard to read and ties your file directly to Doctrine.  It's really up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use YAML for all configuration files, all ... but Doctrine metadatas. I use XML because I like to refer to the XSD to know what kind of node I can use...

For once, XML looks more readable cause each field takes 1 line to be defined. Generally, YAML makes you to break line for each field-node's attribute.

**EDIT:** After 2 years practicing Symfony2, I use almost annotations everywhere for Doctrine metadata, validation rules. I use YAML for translations.

Comment: I think that XML is too much verbose for annotations. Yaml is clear and simple. But I didn't take in account the XSD.